# Should I use absolute pixel values in my Flutter widgets, or should I scale them to the screen?

Tags: flutter, responsive-design

I am coming to Flutter from a web background, where I am used to defining screen elements in terms of percentages of the height and width of the screen, or of elements that contain them.

I just completed a course.

Now that I am enthused and want to start building an app, I am a little confused, as the course only spoke of heights & widths in absolute pixel values. I can see this being problematic with different aspect rations, and especially with different orientations.

Is there a canonical approach to this? The official docs also seem to use absolute pixel values, so maybe I am missing a fundamental point.

A search suggests that I might use [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) and then scale everything according to that. But, I don't see widespread use of that in code samples.

Is there a non-opinionated standard approach?

Comment: well it all depends on the result you really want, as you said MediaQuery is one of the best approach to make aspect ratios, MediaQuery.of(context).size or widgets like AspectRatio() which gives you an aspect ratio based on the maximum width allowed and the ratio of the height you want. It will always depend of what you really want to show in the screen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am a little confused, as the course only spoke of heights & widths in absolute pixel values.

Actually, flutter uses [density independent pixels (dp)](https://material.io/design/layout/pixel-density.html#density-independence) for width/height arguments. dp actually scale with resolution, meaning 1 dp is displayed as the same PHYSICAL distance on every device. You don't have to worry about your elements being displayed at different sizes, just because the resolution of the screen they're on changes.

To be precise, [flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/devicePixelRatio.html) calls them logical pixel and:

> By definition, there are roughly 38 logical pixels per centimeter, or about 96 logical pixels per inch, of the physical display.

So think about them as you would think about cm.

> I am used to defining screen elements in terms of percentages of the height and width of the screen

Nonetheless, you might want to layout your widgets in a relative fashion (relative to the screen or the parent). For that purpose, flutter has different solutions:

1. [Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)
2. [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)
3. [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)
4. [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)
5. [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)
6. [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)
7. [other layout options](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout)

> Is there a non-opinionated standard approach?

It is a very opinionated question to begin with, but for example, [Material design](https://material.io/design/layout/understanding-layout.html#) is a common standard for mobile-design. Flutters layout widgets are based around this approach.

But in the end, it is your design choice. For example, to achieve a responsive layout grid you could use [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html), or you could use [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) and determine yourself how you would like to layout rows and columns.

Comment: "`meaning 1 dp is displayed as the same PHYSICAL distance on every device`" - but, I guess that that doesn;t meant that every device is X by Y pixels? Maybe one is 1.5 X by Y? So, I might still have to scale?

Comment: Mobile devices are driven by interactivity, most layouts use a scrollable element for display of collections. But it can be desirable to change the amount of columns or rows based on available size. For example, you might want to scale a simple grid, because you want to support landscape mode differently to portrait mode. That's what `Wrap` is for. But if you want to adjust the layout and scaling of components in a more refined way (one big component left, 2 smaller ones on the right, etc.), you might need to write the layout logic yourself and use f.e. `LayoutBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to scale widgets based on the size of the screen. This allows your application to be more flexible and adjust to various platforms and sizes such as large tablets or small phones. In order to do this, I recommend you to use the widget **FractionallySizedBox** which allows you to size widgets using a percentage of the screen size. For example, if you want a button widget to fill up 50 percent of a screen's width you can use the following code:

```
Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: FractionallySizedBox(
    widthFactor: 0.5,
    child: FlatButton(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Text("PRESS HERE")
    )
  )
)
```

This code creates a button positioned in the center of the screen with a width of 50 percent of the screen size's width. You can also change the height of the button with the heightFactor field. By using this code the button widget will scale up and scale down for different screen sizes while still maintaining a size of half of the screen's width. For more resources, you should check out this video by the Flutter Team: https://youtu.be/PEsY654EGZ0 and their website on the **FractionallySizedBox** here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html.

The **FractionallySizedBox** however is only one of many different approaches to making your flutter app fit to different screen sizes. Another approach is to use the **AspectRatio** Widget. Below is an example of this:

```
Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: 3/2
    child: FlatButton(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Text("PRESS ME")
    )
  )
)
```

This code will create a button with a 3 to 2 ratio between its width and height. If the screen size changes the button will increase or decrease in size accordingly while again maintaining the 3 to 2 ratio. If you want more information the Flutter team also has a video on it (https://youtu.be/XcnP3_mO_Ms) along with some documentation here:(https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html).

Both widgets are perfectly fine and are considered standard practice to use but I personally use **FractionallySizedBox** more.

I hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: Wow, great answer, thanks. I don't really like aspect ratio, as it seems more likely to lead to distortion.